# Android : Sqlite saves data but while fetching data the value is null

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to save data from API to sqlite database, all my data are saved but when I try to retrieve the data (driver_id) returns null value. Am I getting this problem because I have defined my value driver_id as integer and the API data is coming in string?

My log cat when data is saved:

```
E/LoginCheck: ValueCheck drivername=user driver_id=2 drivercontact=ba 1 kha 2345 busnumber=999999
```

My SQLiteHandler is shown below:

```
 public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_DRIVER_ID = "driver_id";
private static final String KEY_DRIVER_NAME = "drivername";
private static final String KEY_BUS_NUMBER = "busnumber";
private static final String KEY_SCHOOL_UID = "school_id";
private static final String KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER = "drivercontact";

public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_DRIVER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DRIVER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BUS_NUMBER + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created" +CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String drivername, String busnumber, String driver_id, String drivercontact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DRIVER_NAME, drivername); 
    values.put(KEY_BUS_NUMBER, busnumber); 
    values.put(KEY_DRIVER_ID, driver_id); 
    values.put(KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER, drivercontact);

    Log.e("LoginCheck", "ValueCheck " + values.toString());
    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("drivername", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("busnumber", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("driver_id", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("drivercontact", cursor.getString(4));
        Log.e("newvaluecheck", "newvaluecheck " + user.toString());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

    return user;
}

/**
 * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void deleteUsers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
}
```

}

My logcat:

```
E/newvaluecheck: newvaluecheck {drivername=user, driver_id=null, drivercontact=ba 1 kha 2345, busnumber=999999}
```

Comment: This is an unclear question IMO.  You need to point out which lines of code concern the problem.  We shouldn't have to digest 100+ lines of code to find your problem.

Comment: my problem is the driver_id data is saved but when i try to access it, the value is null as shown in logcat

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3))` use this to convert string to int

Answer (score 1):

because you define the table with

`String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_DRIVER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DRIVER_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_BUS_NUMBER + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER + " TEXT" + ")";`

and then extract the data with `SELECT *` (i.e. all columns), the **`driver_id`** offset will be **0** (the very first column) not **3**.

I'd suggest not using hard coded offsets, but rather utilise the Cursor method `getColumnIndex(columname as String)` to provide the actual offset according to the column name.

So I'd suggest using :-

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("drivername", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DRIVER_NAME)));
        user.put("busnumber", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUS_NUMBER)));
        user.put("driver_id", cursor.getString(getColumnIndex(KEY_DRIVER_ID)));
        user.put("drivercontact", cursor.getString(getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTACT_NUMBER)));
        Log.e("newvaluecheck", "newvaluecheck " + user.toString());
```

P.S. not checked so there may be the odd typo.

You could also replace :-

```
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
```

with

```
    if(cursor.moveToFirst) {
```

as `cursor.MoveToFirst` will return false if there is no first row to move to.

You should also really use the correct Cursor get????? method appropriate for the column, e.g. for the `driver_id column`, this would be stored as a long, so rather than:-

`cursor.getString(getColumnIndex(KEY_DRIVER_ID))` you should use :-

`cursor.getLong(getColumnIndex(KEY_DRIVER_ID))`

Not using the appropriate type can result in unexpected results, especially for doubles where String may lose precision.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this `cursor.getString(1)` with `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("KEY_DRIVER_ID"))`